# How to use API routes in your react app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, rest, express

So I made my own API using nodejs, express and mongoDB. I made the routes and tested them with postman and they all work. Now I want to use these routes on my react app but I can't seem to figure out how. I already did something similar with a public API in the app which works but now with using my own API I can't seem to find a proper way to CRUD the data on the page. All help is appreciated !

Here is a link to the Github repository so you can take a look at the code. To clarify it is about showing/making a list not about showing the weather because that already works.

https://github.com/VColson/weatherapp

Please ask if there are any things I need to clarify some more. Thank you !

Comment: Using express in your app, you're looking for Server Side Rendering. Google `React SSR`. A simpler solution would be to externalise your API with a node server and request it from your React app using fetch or axios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this would work better for you if your file tree looked more like this:

```
├── client/
│   ├── index.js
│   └── src/
│       ├── App.js
│       ├── components/
│       └── img/
├── models/
├── public/
├── routes/
└── server.js
```

Your `server.js` is now at the root of the directory, and your react app is within the client folder.

In order to make requests to your routes, you need to be running both servers: the webpack dev server for CRA, and the express server. You can hook them up by following the instructions in [this article](https://daveceddia.com/create-react-app-express-backend/#create-the-react-app). (Starting from "Create the react app" -- you don't need to use express generator for this to work.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I followed the tutorial and changed the file tree and adjusted the locations to the files in the scripts but when I do 'yarn start' in my command line I get an error saying he can't find index.js because he is searching for it in weatherapp/src and not weatherapp/client. How can I adjust this ?

Comment: I just adjusted the file tree a bit and now it's finally working ! Thank you very much !